# Juno Odditiessss

Tags: release-juno

I have found a few oddities with my installation of Juno:

These apps, which are all part of the basic installation, have a blank icon on the menu:

- Calendar
- Mail
- Photos
- Camera
- Videos

These apps have a blank icon in System Settings:

- Applications
- Power
- Sound
- Online Accounts
- Date & Time
- Parental Control

[image]

There is no word-processing application by default, so I have installed Libre Office. The window decorations don't follow my choice of - O X on the right. Same applies to other applications. Can I assume elementaryOS recommends a word-processing app which would do so, and if so which is it?

Comment: The issues you mention are caused by config files inside your /home folder, I've already told you. Juno works fine for everyone else.

Comment: This appeared to me to be a different issue. However, thank you for your carefully considered, polite and helpful response. https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=5903659#post5903659 #14 may interest you.

Comment: Usually some of the icons dissappear when you use elementary tweaks and you choose 'Ubuntu icons' for example. It is because eOS has more default icons compared with the Ubuntu for example.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your screenshot, your installation is using neither the elementary GTK theme or the elementary icon theme which is the cause of the visual oddities you are experiencing.

If this is a clean installation of elementary, I suspect you have mounted an existing home partition which contained configuration that is intefering with elementary's defaults.

It sounds as though you have elementary tweaks installed, so you could remedy this particular issue by using that to set the GTK theme and icon theme to `elementary` in both cases.

However, if the configuration you have has managed to break this, there are likely other things broken too, so I would suggest a clean install without any existing configuration or files where possible.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed some missing icons too; subsequent reboots made them reappear and it hasn't been a problem since. I'm not sure what's going on with your particular system, but if it doesn't resolve itself with a reboot or two, I'd consider a clean reinstall. From your screenshot it looks like you've made some visual tweaks, so unfortunately you're not going to find official help from the dev team.

As for an officially recommended word processor, anything that's officially recommended by the elementary OS team would be under "Curated" in the app store. You won't find any traditional office software in there, but Quilter is pretty great as a markdown editor. Since having the "- O X" isn't officially supported by elementary OS, you're not going to get an officially recommended app that works with it.

Comment: I did use a tweaks app to move the decorations. I have used a couple more and got the decorations where I want them now, even on Writer.  I don't see how that affected the icons though :). They are OK now, but I've no idea how they came back either...